# How to pass user input into char[]

Tags: c++

I followed an example to reverse a string which is great but I would like to enter the string using cin instead of hard coding the value to the char text[]. Can this be done? I have searched on google and found various articles but so far have not been able to make it work.
I tried using c_str() and strcpy (which compiler doesn't like me to use)

```
//Create a char array with text you want to reverse.
char text[] = "hello";


//Get the number of chars in the array, there will be an extra 0 so you need to take 1 away.
int nChars = sizeof(text) - 1;
cout << nChars << endl;

//Make pointer start equal to the text array.
char *pStart = text;

//Make pointer end equal to the text array + number of characters minus 1.
//char *pEnd = text + nChars - 1;
char *pEnd = text + nChars - 1;
cout << pEnd << endl;

//While the start of the pointer is less than the end pointer.
cout << pStart << " " << pEnd << endl;
while (pStart < pEnd) {

    //Save the character at the location of the start pointer.
    char save = *pStart;

    //Make the start pointer equal to the last pointer.
    *pStart = *pEnd;

    //Write the saved character to the end pointer.
    *pEnd = save;

    //Move the start pointer up 1 slot.
    pStart++;
    //Move the end pointer back 1 slot.
    pEnd--;


}


//output text in reverse.
cout << text << endl;

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Use `std::string` when programming in c++ for heavens sake.

Answer (score 1):

> but I would like to enter the string using cin instead of hard coding the value to the `char text[]`.

That's easy to do with c++ using `std::string` instead of a raw char array:

```
 std::string text;

 // ...

 std::getline(cin,text);
```

The rest of the code can work on the `const char*` pointer returned by `text.c_str()`, or even better simply use the [`rbegin()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rbegin) and `rend()` iterators of the string to obtain a reveresed copy:

```
std::copy(text::rbegin(), text.rend(),std::begin(text));
```

From c++17 on you can also use the [`std::reverse()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) function to do that:

```
std::reverse(text.begin(), text.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an aversion to `std::string`, there are many methods to read into a character array.

**Note:  reading into a character array can overflow the array.  Also, there must be a NUL terminating character in the array in order for the array to be treated as a C-style string.**

### Using `cin`

You can use `cin` to read into a character array.

```
char my_array[8];
std::cin >> my_array;
```

This technique will skip initial whitespace, then read characters into `my_array` until whitespace is encountered or the input is terminated.

**Note: if the input is more than the array size, the input will keep writing beyond the end of the array, causing undefined behavior.  Making a huge array may be wasting memory.**

### Using `read`

You can read a fixed number of characters using the `read` method:
static const unsigned int LIMIT = 16;

```
char your_array[LIMIT];
std::cin.read(your_array, LIMIT);
```

Using the above code, you will need to place the NUL terminating character in the appropriate location:

```
size_t count = std::cin.gcount();
if (count == LIMIT)
{
    --count;
}
your_array[count] = '\0';
```

### Using `std::string`:

The preference is to use `std::string`:

```
std::string input_text;
std::cin >> input_text;  // Read space separated text, i.e. a *word*.
std::getline(std::cin, input_text);  // Read a line of text.
```

Comment: What about the _reverse_ part?

Comment: I'm answering the title of the question and the first sentence.

Comment: Thank you that's really helpful, you see what I was trying to achieve and offered some good explanations.

Answer (score -1):

```
int ReverseStringProg() {

    string text;
    cout << "Please enter a value that you would like to reverse: " << flush;
    cin >> text;
    std::reverse(text.begin(), text.end());
    cout << text;
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: I am not sure how that concisely answers your question. There's only code without any explanations.

Comment: _" thank you for the negative votes, that helps a lot."_ Sure it does fo future research.